NestJS Mongoose Connection Error: "MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017"
I'm working on a NestJS application that connects to a MongoDB database using the Mongoose module. Everything was working fine until I encountered the following error:
[Nest] 3372  - 08/24/2024, 9:32:12 PM   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (C:\Users\Tarek\Desktop\auth\my-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:897:11)
    at NativeConnection.asPromise (C:\Users\Tarek\Desktop\auth\my-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:1360:11)
    at C:\Users\Tarek\Desktop\auth\my-app\node_modules\@nestjs\mongoose\dist\mongoose-core.module.js:40:125

Here is the relevant part of my AppModule:
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { UserSchema } from './auth/schemas/user.schema';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost:27017/MyApp'),
    AuthModule,
    // Other modules
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}


I'm running MongoDB locally, and both mongod and mongosh work fine without any issues.
I've confirmed that MongoDB is listening on the default port 27017.
The application fails to connect and keeps retrying, but the connection is refused.
What I've Tried:
Verified that MongoDB is running on localhost:27017.
Checked firewall and network settings to ensure that the connection isn't being blocked.
Restarted the MongoDB service.
Question:
What might be causing this connection refusal, and how can I resolve it? Is there something I'm missing in my NestJS or Mongoose configuration?

I fixed the issue by switching Node.js versions using nvm. I was initially using Node.js 18.18.0, which caused errors when running npm install mongodb@^5.9.2. After switching to Node.js 16.20.0 with nvm use 16.20.0, the errors were resolved and everything is working fine now.

@ray error ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 is different to ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 your link is rather confusing

@WernfriedDomscheit The answer with the highest score also use the same solution of replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1, but I agree that your answer has a clearer title and far better explanation.

Yes, unbelievable. It provides a colorful mixture of answers for these two errors, and most of them are not related to the actual question.

The problem is, the mongo can run on cluster, so the mongo driver try to find the other mongo instances.
Yoiu can avoid this wen you use the ?directConnection=true  in you connection string, like this
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost:27017/MyApp?directConnection=true'),
    AuthModule,
    // Other modules
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})

directConnection
Specifies whether the client connects directly to the host[:port] in the connection URI:

true: The client sends operations to only the specified host. It doesn't attempt to discover any other members of the replica set.

false: The client attempts to discover all servers in the replica set, and sends operations to the primary member. This is the default value.


